# Is there a limit on number of Recommendations in Email-Recommendations in Personalization Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am using the 'Email Recommendation Logic'. In that when I select a Layout of up to 4(ie 2*2) it is working fine but when I select more than 4 I don't get any items in the preview and in the email when I send Email.
Is there a limit on the number of Recommendations in Email-Recommendations in Personalization Builder?

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit that is been set by salesforce if you want to use basic email recommendations (without any adjustments or coding) this is 4x4 aka 16 Elements for Mail Recommendations.

It is most likely that your scenario definitions are not ideal for the account you test that email recommendations with. Maybe you can change to Waterfall recommendations, than it takes all the elements of the scenarios that are in your scenario order.

Be aware that sending emails with mail recommendations consumes super messages (afaik).